# How can i cut a LocalDateTime format string to limit year from 4 digits to two?

Tags: java, string, split, localdatetime

I have a String with a date and time, for example `11/12/2020 10:45`, so in this format. I want to cut it so its 7th and 8th character disappear so I get like `11/12/20 10:45`. How can i do it? I've been looking to the `.split()` method of Strings but it don't cut in number of characters but with a regular expression.

Comment: You can just use the substring method of String: 
String part1 = myDate.substring(0, 6)
String part2 = myDate.substring(7)

Comment: but it is not what i need to. After the date, i have an hour to save, so i need to crop a part of the String and delete it, it is in the middle of the String.

Comment: Can you show an example of such a string, and state which two characters you want?

Comment: With substring you can choose the endIndex and the fromIndex. Maybe you should try it out. myDate.substring(0,6) returns the first 6 characters. myDate.substring(8) returns the part from index 8, so the ninth character (sorry, my code used 7, I will edit it). I see I can't edit my previous reply, but you get the point.

In addition, if you want to create one string out of it you can just append the one to the other using:   myDate.substring(0,6) + myDate.substring(8)

Comment: my String is made from a DATE and a TIME inputs from jsp. I were trying to fix the format, since the DATE comes as '2020-11-25', and i need it as '25/11/20'. I did use the substring and it worked. So thanks!

Answer (score 3):

> I have a String with a date. I want to cut it so its 7 and 8 character dissapear.

This is doable, of course - that is what `substring` is for. But that's not your problem. Your problem is: I have a date; I wish to render it in a certain fashion. There is a bad way to solve this problem which involves substring, and you're now asking questions about the bad strategy for solving your problem. Let's not bother with answers that support silly directions of solving the underlying problem. `split` is similarly string manipulation.

### Okay, so how do I do this?

Where-ever possible, if you have a well defined concept, then use that. You have the concept of a date. Hopefully it is in the form of an instance of `LocalDateTime`. If it is not, then let's make that happen:

```
String input = "2022-12-10 14:10:45";
DateTimeFormatter IN_FORMAT = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
// adjust the pattern to match whatever you have, of course.
LocalDateTime mark = LocalDateTime.parse(input, IN_FORMAT);
```

Now that we have an LDT instance, the job becomes: Okay, so how do I format this as a string such that only 2 digits are used for the year? That's.. easy.

```
DateTimeFormatter OUT_FORMAT = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-uu HH:mm");
String out = OUT_FORMAT.format(mark);
```

Comment: yeah, i tried using a formatter, but didn't work, i don't know what happened but yeah,